# Proving in a Borel space that $\bigcup_\limits{k=1}^{n}A_k=A$ and $\mu(A_k)=\frac{\mu(A)}{n}$ for any $k=1,...,n$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $(E,\mathscr{E})$ be a Borel space and let $\mu$ be an atom-free measure(that is, $\mu({x})=0$ for any $x\in E$). Show that for any $A\in\mathscr{E}$ and any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exist a pairwise disjoint sets $A_1,...,A_n\in\mathscr{E}$ with $\bigcup_\limits{k=1}^{n}A_k=A$ and $\mu(A_k)=\frac{\mu(A)}{n}$ for any $k=1,...,n$.(Probability theory, Alchim Klenke)

The fact that $(E,\mathscr{E})$ is a Borel space means there is a map, let's say $\phi:(E,\mathscr{E})\to(B,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ that is an isomorphism. If I could say that $(E,\mathscr{E})$ is a seperable space then there would be a countable number of sets for any set. However there is no topology associated with $(E,\mathscr{E})$, therefore I cannot talk about isometry.

**Question**:

How should I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably enough to prove it for $n=2$ and use base 2 expansion of the $1/n$ for $n\geq 3$. Are you sure about the definition of Borel space? I don't know it myself, but it seems very restrictive. **EDIT** Wikipedia gives a similar but slightly different definition of Borel space.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat The definition in my book is defined as an isomorphism. That means a bijective map $\phi$ as defined above that is measurable and whose inverse is also measurable.

Comment: Ok.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @OlivierBégassat What do you mean by base 2 and expansion?

Comment: So you should just work directly in $\mathbb{R}$ where it is pretty easy.

Comment: You don't need base $2$ expansion if you work directly in $\mathbb{R}$. Just show that there are real numbers (which you might approximate using rational numbers) $x_1<\cdots<x_{n-1}$ with $\mu(A\cap(-\infty,x_k])=\frac{k\mu(A)}n$.

Comment: This is a classic measure theory problem on $\mathbb{R}$ which can be solved in that situation by proving that @OlivierBégassat 's function $f(y):= \mu(A \cap (-\infty, y])$ is continuous, and then using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat                      Thanks for your assistance! On this expression $\mu(A\cap(-\infty,x_k])=\frac{k\mu(A)}n$. How can you intersect $A\in E$ with an real line interval? They are not on the same space. Where does the $k$ come from?

Comment: @Dzoooks I ask you the same question. On this expression $\mu(A\cap(-\infty,x_k])=\frac{k\mu(A)}n$. How can $A\in\mathscr{E}$ intersect an real line interval?

Comment: Using @Dzooks approach, consider $f(x)=\mu(A\cap\phi^{-1}(]-\infty,x]))$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I am not seeing how the intermediate value theorem relates to the question. I need to find a countable number of disjoint sets whose union is $A$.

Comment: Can you prove the statement about the existence of $x_k$ such that $\mu(A\cap\phi^{-1}(]-\infty,x_k]))=\frac{k}n\mu(A)$? If so, you are 99% done. The existence of such $x_k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n-1$ can be proven with the IVT or by approximating them with rational numbers.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks for your support. I do not understand where the $k$ comes from. Are $x_1,...x_k$  real numbers? How would I apply the IVT on that case? I am really sorry but I am lost. If you feel like posting an answer I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Dzooks, consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\mu(A\cap\phi^{-1}(]-\infty,x]))$$
This map is nondecreasing, has $\lim_{-\infty}f=0$ and $\lim_{+\infty}f=\mu(A)$ by standard properties of measures. Furthermore, $f$ is continuous since $\mu$ has no atoms. Thus there are real numbers $x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{n-1}$ such that $f(x_k)=\frac{k}n\mu(A)$ for all $k=1,\dots,n-1$. Then set, for $k=1,\dots,n-1$
$$A_k=\begin{cases}
A\cap\phi^{-1}(]-\infty,x_1]) & \text{if }k=1\\
A\cap\phi^{-1}(]x_{k-1},x_k]) & \text{if }1<k<n\\
A\cap\phi^{-1}(]x_{n-1},+\infty[) & \text{if }k=n\\
\end{cases}$$
The $A_k$ are disjoint, cover $A$ and all have $\mu$ measure $\frac1n\mu(A)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry to reply so late but I have a doubt. When was the continuity of $f $ used in the proof?

Comment: ``Thus there are real numbers...'' uses the intermediate value theorem.